# How to scrape the on click link of an href that's not https?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

First time experimenting with Python and scraping - in the following exercise, I scrape a page and I print all the href found, although some of them are not https. In this latter case, how can I scrape the actual https I would get on click? I tried and failed to figure out how to interact with the "onLinkClick" event.

Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://onepiecetopdecks.com/deck-list/english-format-op1-and-st1to4-meta-decks/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

Comment: There's no real way to do this with `requests`, since it does not understand javascript.  You'll probably have to use some other tool that does understand javascript, such as selenium.

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the actual https link that would be followed when clicking on an href that is not https, you would need to use a web browser automation library such as Selenium. Selenium allows you to interact with a web page as if you were a user, including clicking on links and navigating to new pages.